# Add elements to jsTree from array

Tags: php, jquery, jstree

I have element names like "xyz" or "abc" with 1/2/4/5/6/7/10 as its path or the parent relationship.

The entire thing is in an array.

I want to generate a jsTree with respect to the path which provides the parent to the child reference.

like, 
if

- abc - 1/2
- bvg - 1/2
- xyz - 1
- yui - 1

The tree should be like:-

- xyz

  - abc
  - bvg
- yui

I am using http://www.jstree.com/ [open to other suggestions].

Using a basic php page with jQuery.

Comment: How does it know that abc and bvg should have xyz as the parent instead of yui?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that instead of saving the path in the array the array reflects the structure of the tree.

Instead of:

```
array (
     'abc' => '1/2',
     'bvg' => '1/2',
     'xyz' => '1',
     'yui' => '1'
)
```

you have:

```
array (
     0 => array('xyz' => array ('abc', 'bvg')),
     1 => 'yui'
)
```

Comment: Yes, that seems a better way of storing the data. But still my question remains how do i generate a tree using jQuery?